# Hibernate Eagerly Loading Lazy Entities when using @Query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

Hibernate seems to be eagerly loading a Lazy Loaded entity whenever I use my own repository methods annotated with @Query. It doesn't happen when I call the built in repository methods from JpaRepository.

My entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_entities")
@Data
public class ParentEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mappingField", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<ChildEntity> childEntities;
}
```

My repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<ParentEntity, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p.isRemoved = false")
    Set<ParentEntity> findAllRemovedIsFalse();
}
```

When I execute the following code, I can see that Hibernate is eagerly loading my lazily loaded entities, only when I call my `findAllRemovedIsFalse()` method, but not when I call `findById()` defined in `CrudRepository`.

```java
public class TestClass 
{
    private ParentService parentService;

    public void myMethod()
    {
        var jpaMethodEntity = repository.findById(1L).get();
        var queryMethodEntities = parentService.getEntities();
        var queryMethodEntity = queryMethodEntity.stream().skip(1L).findFirst().get();

        log.info(Hibernate.isInitialized(jpaMethodEntity.getChildEntities()));
        log.info(Hibernate.isInitialized(queryMethodEntity.getChildEntities()));
    }
}

public class ParentService
{
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Set<ParentEntity> getEntities()
    {
        return parentRepository.findAllRemovedIsFalse();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Why is this happening?

UPDATE: I updated the code a bit to show more the relationship between the classes, particularly the location of the `@Transactional` annotation. Very interestingly, I've found that I can call `CrudRepository.findById()` outside a transaction, because it seems to by default wrap that method in it's own transaction.

This is important because I've found that if I annotate `myMethod()` with `@Transactional`, then suddenly they both entities are showing as having intialized the lazy loaded entities. This makes sense, because I'm still in a transaction so it should load the entities, but it doesn't explain why the entities are eagerly loaded even when I am outside of the transaction, as in the example.

Comment: Does repository.findAllRemovedIsFalse().stream().findFirst() select the same entity with id 1? Check that jpaMethodEntity and queryMethodEntity are different objects.

Comment: They were indeed the same objects, but I just updated my test to ensure that they weren't the same object and the issue still occurs.